# Is it good to accept answers which actually give alternatives instead of answers?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I know it's all about reputation here but:

I'm unsure now if it is recommended to accept an answer or not when it doesn't really answer the question but rather gives an alternative that avoids my problem (which I in [my case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47178713/7111561) appreciated a lot and would like to accept).

Of course the problem behind the question is solved by this answer but it might mislead other users in future who actually are rather looking for an answer to the question as is.

Comment: "*I know it's all about reputation here but:*" - What exactly do you mean?

Comment: The accepted answer is for fixing your issue, not other peoples.

Comment: I mean it would be nice for the user who posted the answer to get the reputation for it as accepted answer.

Comment: Ah ok @George thanks. Maybe I think very global sometimes

Comment: @derHugo it's good to think globally when asking questions and answering them most of the time, but an accepted answer mark just means that this worked for the OP, if someone else posts and answer which is better but doesn't work for you, the voting system should make sure other people see it